# Continue inserting data from multiples arrays even if one of them is empty

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm creating a kind of multilingual dictionary with words from different languages on the same row with php, mysql and laravel. I insert the data from arrays with different length with a for loop. My problem is that the loop will stop as soon as one of the arrays is empty. I'd like to continue inserting data as long as all the arrays aren't empty, even if it means that some columns will be NULL in the database.

```
$words = request()->json()->all();
$base_words = array_column($words, 'baseForm');
$fr = array_column($words, 'fr');
$en = array_column($words, 'en');
$es = array_column($words, 'es');
$it = array_column($words, 'it');
$de = array_column($words, 'de');

for ($i = 0; $i < max($fr, $en, $es, $it, $de); $i++) {
  Word::insert([
    'ru' => $base_words[$i],
    'fr' => $fr[$i],
    'en' => $en[$i],
    'es' => $es[$i],
    'it' => $it[$i],
    'de' => $de[$i]
  ]);
}
```

Here is how my $words array looks like with dd() (I deleted some entries or the array would have been to long).

```
array:56 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "baseForm" => "да"
    "es" => "sí"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "baseForm" => "да"
    "es" => "y"
  ]
  15 => array:2 [
    "baseForm" => "да"
    "it" => "e"
  ]
  20 => array:2 [
    "baseForm" => "да"
    "fr" => "oui"
  ]
  28 => array:2 [
    "baseForm" => "да"
    "en" => "yes"
  ]
  29 => array:2 [
    "baseForm" => "да"
    "en" => "yeah"
  ]
]
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who would like to help me on this.

EDIT: Here comes the full working code for people that it could interest :

```
    $words = request()->json()->all();
    $base_words = array_column($words, 'baseForm');
    $declined_words = array_column($words, 'declinedForm');
    $fr = array_column($words, 'fr');
    $en = array_column($words, 'en');
    $es = array_column($words, 'es');
    $it = array_column($words, 'it');
    $de = array_column($words, 'de');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count(max($fr, $en, $es, $it, $de)); $i++) {
      Word::insert([
        'ru' => isset($base_words[$i]) ? $base_words[$i] : null,
        'fr' => isset($fr[$i]) ? $fr[$i] : null,
        'en' => isset($en[$i]) ? $en[$i] : null,
        'es' => isset($es[$i]) ? $es[$i] : null,
        'it' => isset($it[$i]) ? $it[$i] : null,
        'de' => isset($de[$i]) ? $de[$i] : null
      ]);
      }
```

EDIT: new JSON structure

```
{
  "жаловаться": [
      {
        "word": "se plaindre",
        "lang": "fr"
      },
      {
        "word": "se lamenter",
        "lang": "fr"
      },
      {
        "word": "gémir",
        "lang": "fr"
      },
      {
        "word": "se désoler",
        "lang": "fr"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the `$words` variable?

Comment: Sure, I edited my original post.

Comment: Add the error you get.

Comment: What you're doing makes little sense. You're trying to store translations without a base word (that happens whenever `$base_words[$i]` is not set). Your JSON structure is pretty suboptimal - you should try to group all the translations by the base form. Your database structure seems suboptimal as well - if multiple translations of a single word are possible in your system, you should rather have a column for the language of the translation instead of having a column for every language and inserting a whole bunch of empty values inside them.

Comment: I'm not sure that you get what I want to achieve and how my db looks like but anyway I appreciate your help. I have a column for each language ru | fr | en | es | it The base word is always a russian word since I want to add the definition of a russian word and all the synonyms for this word in every languages. Like that I will have a dictionary from russian to all the other languages : ru-fr ru-en ru-it etc. Do you still think all is suboptimal?

Comment: The structure you have would be fine if you had one possible translation. But your sample data suggests otherwise. So, either it is suboptimal or your sample data is not a good sample. Do you allow multiple translations of the same word?

Comment: Hello @El_Vanja I worked on the JSON structure to get closer to what you described. I edited my first post. Do you think it's better now?

Comment: Yes, that would be much easier to process because all the related data is grouped. Well done!

Comment: @El_Vanja It was the first time I generate JSON dynamically from API data. Thanks for your help. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that your insert breaks because you're not having the same number of elements in all arrays.

So if you had 4 elements in the array1 but 7 in the array2, when you try to access array1[5], it would break.

You can try with the following:

```
$words = request()->json()->all();
$base_words = array_column($words, 'baseForm');
$fr = array_column($words, 'fr');
$en = array_column($words, 'en');
$es = array_column($words, 'es');
$it = array_column($words, 'it');
$de = array_column($words, 'de');

for ($i = 0; $i < max($fr, $en, $es, $it, $de); $i++) {
  Word::insert([
    'ru' => isset($base_words[$i]) ? $base_words[$i] : null,
    'fr' => isset($fr[$i]) ? $fr[$i] : null,
    'en' => isset($en[$i]) ? $en[$i] : null,
    'es' => isset($es[$i]) ? $es[$i] : null,
    'it' => isset($it[$i]) ? $it[$i] : null,
    'de' => isset($de[$i]) ? $de[$i] : null
  ]);
}
```

Or provide the complete error.

Comment: Your code add all the data as I wanted, but then keeps adding data with value of NULL for thousands rows.

Comment: Didn't you say: I'd like to continue inserting data as long as all the arrays aren't empty, even if it means that some columns will be NULL in the database??

Comment: let's say the array with french translations ($fr) is the longest one with 15 elements. Then I want to add these 15 elements event if it means that the italian column in the DB will be null because italian ($it) array has only 3 elements. But I want to stop adding data after 15 rows.

Comment: Thank you N L, for the ones that it could help, I solved the endless data adding in the db by wrapping the max() function with count() : count(max($fr, $en, $es, $it, $de))

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you could do the following:

```
$words = request()->json()->all();
$base_words = array_column($words, 'baseForm');
$fr = array_column($words, 'fr');
$en = array_column($words, 'en');
$es = array_column($words, 'es');
$it = array_column($words, 'it');
$de = array_column($words, 'de');

for ($i = 0; $i < max($fr, $en, $es, $it, $de); $i++) {

if (isset($base_words[$i])) {
  Word::insert([
   'ru' => $base_words[$i],
  ]);
}

if (isset($fr[$i]) {
  Word::insert([
   'fr' => $fr[$i],
  ]);
}
```

}

And continue like this for each language. This should resolve your problem.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it inserts the base_word in a row, and then the fr_word in the next row. I want all the languages on the same row. Thank you anyway for trying to help me.

Comment: Come on dude, you just need to put before for loop something like: $aaa = Word, and then in insert whatever you need to insert. If any of my responses helped, you can upvote them...